# Parse XML text to identify the node values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to parse an XML file that I get from a url (sample below) and I need to parse the items that are on the record node.  I am planning to put it into a SQL database with code at the bottom but can't figure out that line of code

```
<pmcids status="ok">
<request idtype="pmid" pmids="" versions="yes" showaiid="no">
<echo>ids=19240239;tool=HCC;email=morgenxxx%40xxxx.edu;format=xml</echo>
</request>
<record requested-id="19240239" pmcid="PMC2668929" pmid="19240239" doi="10.1158/1055-9965.EPI-08-0866">
<versions><version pmcid="PMC2668929.1" mid="NIHMS104698" current="true"/>
</versions>
</record>
</pmcids>
```

SQL code:

```
nref.value('@PMID[1]','varchar(max)') pmid,
            nref.value('@PMCID[1]','varchar(max)') PMCID
```

All help is appreciated.  I hope that this is enough information to determine the correct syntax

Comment: I would highly recommend to use OPENXML if you can. Why? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e51ef84d-72d6-490a-844a-fe28fbea3648/xml-performance-comparison-why-is-openxml-faster?forum=sqlxml

Comment: Good explanation on OPENXML: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1609/replacing-openxml-with-the-xml-nodes-function-in-sql-server-2005/

Comment: Use bcp.exe which comes with SQL server.  See following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx

Comment: OPENXML looks cool and works with 2012 out of the box -- I think that will work   Thanks

Comment: I would much rather use the built-in, native XQuery support in SQL Server! Much easier to grasp than OPENXML ! ....

Answer (score 3):

Use the native XQuery support in SQL Server! Much simpler than OPENXML ....

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<pmcids status="ok">
<request idtype="pmid" pmids="" versions="yes" showaiid="no">
<echo>ids=19240239;tool=HCC;email=morgenxxx%40xxxx.edu;format=xml</echo>
</request>
<record requested-id="19240239" pmcid="PMC2668929" pmid="19240239" doi="10.1158/1055-9965.EPI-08-0866">
   <versions>
       <version pmcid="PMC2668929.1" mid="NIHMS104698" current="true"/>
   </versions>
</record>
</pmcids>'

SELECT
    RequestedId = xc.value('@requested-id', 'int'),
    pmcid = xc.value('@pmcid', 'varchar(50)'),
    pmid = xc.value('@pmid', 'int'),
    doi = xc.value('@doi', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/pmcids/record') AS XT(XC)
```

Basically, the `.nodes()` call returns a "virtual" table `XT` with a column `XC` that contains the XML fragment for each of the XML nodes that match your XPath expression - here a list of all `<record>` nodes under the `<pmcids>` root node.

Then, using the `.value()` call, you can "reach into" each of those nodes in the XML elements and retrieve the individual bits - since those are all attributes, you the `@` prefix to indicate an attribute, and define the data type of your attribute.

This gives me an output of:

[image]

which you could easily insert into a database table

**Update:** if you also need the `mid` from the `<version>` node - use this:

```
SELECT
    RequestedId = xc.value('@requested-id', 'int'),
    pmcid = xc.value('@pmcid', 'varchar(50)'),
    pmid = xc.value('@pmid', 'int'),
    doi = xc.value('@doi', 'varchar(50)'),
    VersionPmcid = xver.value('@pmcid', 'varchar(50)'),
    mid = xver.value('@mid', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    @input.nodes('/pmcids/record') AS XT(XC)
CROSS APPLY
    XC.nodes('versions/version') AS XT2(XVer)
```

*(I added the `pmcid` attribute from the `<version>` node, since there might be multiple `<version>` nodes under a `<record>` from what this sample looks like)*

Comment: This is perfect and what I was originally looking for.  How would I pull the mid value in the version node?  I was playing with OPENXML and trying to do that was messy requiring two different tables, two different Selects etc

Comment: I see the version information now-- I did not refresh the page to see your update.  This is 100% perfect-- did I say perfect?